# Creating a folder that aggregates files from other folders

Tags: scripting, symlink, utilities

I'm trying to organise my directories for different classes such that each of them has a todo folder.

something like this:

```
|--classes/
|  |--classOne/
|  |  |--todo/
|  |  |  |--read.pdf
|  |  |--otherFiles.md
|  |--classTwo
|  |  |--todo/
|  |  |  |--read.pdf
|  |  |--otherFiles.md
|  |--classThree
|  |  |--todo/
|  |  |  |--read.pdf
|  |  |--otherFiles.md
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a folder called `todo_buffer` external to this hierarchy that can aggregate data from all of the individual `todo` folders.

It's possible to just create a small application, but is there a unix-utility that will allow me to do this? I was thinking along the line of symbolic links.

Comment: If you're thinking about symbolic links, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've only used symlinks in the context of `ln -s`, where i'm just soft linking two files and truncating their path. I read the `ln` manpage, but couldn't figure out how I might achieve this, which is why I turned to SE

Answer (score 1):

`stow` it will create the symlinks, and maintain them. You have to run it to get it to update. However you could use `inotify-wait`, to trigger an update.

Comment: The next question would be how to get `stow` to only stow the files in the `todo` directories, and how to get `inotify-wait` to trigger that.

Comment: OK so ask another question, but have a go first. If you show no effort, then you may not get a good response.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p todo_buffer

for todo in classes/class*/todo/read.pdf
do
    class=${todo%/todo/read.pdf} # Get the name of
    class=${class#classes/}      # the class directory

    ln -s "../$todo" "todo_buffer/$class-read.pdf"
done
```

This script is supposed to be run in the parent directory of the `classes` directory.  It will simply create a `todo_buffer` directory and then proceed to loop over the pathnames of the `read.pdf` files in the `todo` subdirectories of each class.

This assumes that the directory structure below the `classes` directory is as you have shown, with each class having a subdirectory called `class<something>`.

For each `read.pdf` file, a symbolic link is created in the `todo_buffer` directory.

The symbolic links points to `../classes/.../todo/read.pdf`, i.e. it's relative to the location of the link. If you need absolute pathnames for the links, replace `../` with `$PWD/` in the call to `ln -s`.

Given the following directories and files:

```
.
|-- classes
|   |-- class-1
|   |   |-- otherFiles.md
|   |   `-- todo
|   |       `-- read.pdf
|   |-- class-2
|   |   |-- otherFiles.md
|   |   `-- todo
|   |       `-- read.pdf
|   `-- class-3
|       |-- otherFiles.md
|       `-- todo
|           `-- read.pdf
`-- script.sh

7 directories, 7 files
```

Running the script would generate:

```
todo_buffer/
|-- class-1-read.pdf -> ../classes/class-1/todo/read.pdf
|-- class-2-read.pdf -> ../classes/class-2/todo/read.pdf
`-- class-3-read.pdf -> ../classes/class-3/todo/read.pdf

0 directory, 3 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your requirements and the context of your problem further?

1. Would you use the "tool" to aggregate your todo_buffer folder AFTER you populated all the todo folders or BEFORE in order for you to more easily populate these todo folders?
2. Would each individual todo folders contain similar filenames (as shown in your example) but with actual different content?

Symbolic links might be what you are looking for (yet I feel you would need to write a small script) but it really depends on what you want to exactly achieve.

Symbolic link works with the same logic as a copy or a move:

```
ln -s {src} {dst}
```

where {src} is the file where the link should be pointing to and {dst} is the symbolic name.

Suppose all your files are in todo_buffers and you only want to create symbolic links in each of the todo folders then:

```
cd {some path}/classes/classOne/todo   
ln -s {path to todo_buffer}/todo_buffer/read.pdf  read.pdf  
cd {some path}/classes/classTwo/todo  
ln -s {path to todo_buffer}/todo_buffer/read.pdf  read.pdf  
cd {some path}/classes/classThree/todo  
ln -s {path to todo_buffer}/todo_buffer/read.pdf  read.pdf  
...
```

Comment: There may be similarly named files within the `todo` folder, but that's unlikely. Any recommendations for how to setup the symlinks? I read the `ln` manpage, but couldn't figure out how I might achieve this.